# Should I respond with 404 or 405 if the wrong method is used and I don't know if the resource exists?

Tags: http, web-applications, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-405

**Background:** Let's say I have a website that displays info about a collection of Foos. The URL:s are on the form:

```
https://example.com/foo/{foo-id}
```

I only respont to GET requests - you can not POST or PUT or DELETE a Foo. Checking if a certain ID corresponds to a real Foo is an expensive operation, that I want to avoid.

**Question:** How do I respond to a POST request to `/foo/12345`? The ideal would be to check if such a Foo exists. If so, send a 405 (Method Not Allowed). If not, send a 404 (Not Found). But checking if the Foo exist is expensive, and I don't want to waste the energy on some idiot who can't even be bothered to use the right method.

So then I am left with two options:

- Always respond with 404, even though there might actually be something there.
- Always respons with 405, even though there might not be anything there and the user agent will be greeted with a 404 if it resends the request with the right method.

Which option is most in line with the HTTP standard? Is any of them persuant to the standard at all?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there's not a strict rule about this in terms of the HTTP specification itself.

However my personal opinion on this is that in the steps of deciding what kind of response to give to a request, checking the request *type* should come before checking the request *path* (to see if it's even there).

Consider that for some situations it would be a reasonable approach to even configure your webserver (or load balancer) to simply block all the wrong types of request methods.. before the request even makes its way up to your web software. This again suggests to me that you should check the request method before the path.

And then added to the fact that you're saying that checking if a *Foo* even exists is an expensive operation, it seems prudent to confirm that they've taken the care to send the right request in the first place!

So yes, I would always just return a 405 in that case.